# What does the SOS mechanic do?

Tags: persona-5, persona-4-golden

In Persona 4 and 5, in dungeons, there is a way to call for an SOS. I often do it by accident. (it's mapped to Start and I can't seem to program my brain to not think its the open menu to heal option)

It is explained as 'getting help from other players via the internet'. I also sometimes get calls to help someone else.

But really, I can't seem to figure out what it does in reality, and what I get from helping others?

So in the Persona help mechanic, what does the mechanic do for the player that is helped, and what reward is there for the helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, people who are playing at the same time as you are, and who are also online, and also in a dungeon, and also have an SOS sent out, can 'hear' your SOS and choose to respond to it by clicking the SOS button.

At the start of your next battle, all your characters recover 4 HP and SP for each responder, and regardless of what happens the count and the SOS call are reset once combat ends.

It's... Not exactly an overwhelming boost.

Comment: Especially when you are playing months after release and the players are not pretty much all in the same dungeon like in release day.